# cannot add extra spaces '&nbsp;' in chrome developer tools while editing

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-dev-editor

I was trying to add extra spaces `(&nbsp;)` inside a div tag in Elements section in chrome developer tools.

```
<div>hello&nbsp;&nbsp;world</div>
```

The above renders as literal.

Expected:

```
hello  world
```

Actual:

```
hello&nbsp;&nbsp;world
```

Comment: Is your problem that you don't how to type a non breaking space?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question and is actually looking for a way to add *non-breaking space characters* (`&nbsp;`) into the Developer Tools Elements panel you can do so by right-clicking the element that contains the value you want to add your characters to (or any of its parent elements) and selecting "Edit as HTML".

While double-clicking the value and adding `&nbsp;` will show `&nbsp;` as text in the browser, editing as HTML will correctly show the non-breaking space character as expected.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. Short and precise.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Chrome's Developer Tools, you don't need to worry about **[HTML entities](http://webcheatsheet.com/html/ref_entities.php)**.

Simply writing the code as you would in an IDE works as expected -- entering
`<div>hello world</div>` results in a `<div>` being created with the contents `hello world`.

Using multiple spaces will also work in this manner:
`<div>hello  world</div>` results in a `<div>` being created with the contents `hello  world`.

Here is **this very answer** manipulated in this way:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: I actually need more than one extra space, Sorry I will update the question

Comment: Writing out the spaces as actual spaces will work even when more than one space is entered.

Comment: It certainly should -- I just did it in my Chrome Developer Tools right now with success. Are you actually using the Chrome Developer Tools when you encounter this issue? What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add an image showcasing manipulating this very answer in the above way.

Comment: actually the problem is when I edit it inside some tag, it doesn't encode but when I create a new element and then add spaces it works fine. thanks for the answer though, it led me to what I want.