# How browser remembers to insert a space without showing it in the markup

Tags: reactjs, dom

> How does the browser remember that space has to be inserted between both span element to show ***Hello World*** without having any information about it inside the markup

```
const element = React.createElement('div',{
                   children:[
                      React.createElement('span',null,'Hello'),
                      ' ',
                      React.createElement('span',null,'Hello')
                   ]
                })
```

But when I saw the mark-up which was rendered in the markup was

```
<div>
   <span>Hello</span>
   <span>World</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not about ["how browser remembers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029894/cannot-add-extra-spaces-nbsp-in-chrome-developer-tools-while-editing) (HTML entities) but "why I don't see space in dev tools".

You can see the space in Accessibility tab:

[image]

If you want to "see the space" as an elemet you can use non-breaking space:

```
<span>Hello</span>&nbsp;<span>World</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because browsers understand elements when reading HTML so just a space `" "` won't do anything. Try adding a span with space in his innerHTML